# sublime text 3 and python's command "print"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

SublimeText 3, Python 3.5.(system default), Python 2.7 (not system default)

I have a code:

```
import os
import sys

print (os.getcwd())
a=os.listdir("D:")
print (a)
if a:print ("is a")
print ("123")
```

the result in Sublime Text is the following:

```
D:\
is a
123
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

question: where is the result of:

```
a=os.listdir("D:")
print (a)
```

???????

In Python IDLE - everything works great. result is the folowing:

```
C:\Windows\System32
['! Docs', '! Install', '! Music', '$RECYCLE.BIN', '05.mkv', '1.mp3', '1.txt', '15.py' ]
is a
123
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be because `Python IDLE` uses absolute paths, while running script from `Sublime 3` probably points to relative path from where are you executing the script. That's why it doesn't seem to detect `D:` directory which is being your parent directory in this case.

It's not `print` command that is wrong, it's actually `os.listdir("D:")` which is empty.

Comment: I doubt there's a folder in the OP's working directory called `'D:'`, and if a folder doesn't exist, that'll raise an error. If the folder exists and is simply empty, the result is an empty `list` (`[]`), not nothing.

Comment: Guys, thanx for your answers, but I didn't understand - how to make it work?